# Html set default toggle

Tags: html, css, toggle, accordion

I open and close toggle if i click to href=#collapseFive

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion5" href="#collapseFive">    
    <strong><i class="icon-caret-down"></i>SomeText</strong>
 </a>
 <div id="collapseFive"  class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

I want to set default **toggle** "**open**" for **div id="collapseFive"  class="panel-collapse** collapse"

So how can do this **without** javascript ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Toggle CSS3 Accordion on Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443339/how-to-toggle-css3-accordion-on-click)

Comment: this might be helpful : http://thenittygritty.co/toggle-navigation-with-pure-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not giving you complete solution but you can try this way.. please open this fiddle:

```
<label for="menu-toggle">Click me to toggle menu</label>  
<input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle"/>  
<ul id="menu">  
  <li><a href="#">First link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Third link</a></li>
</ul>
```

css

```
label {  
  cursor: pointer;
}
#menu-toggle {
  display: none; /* hide the checkbox */
}
#menu {
  display: none;
}
#menu-toggle:checked + #menu {
  display: block;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amitkansal/HG5ZJ/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't set the data-* attributes using **only** CSS. That requires attribute values (other that "style") to be changed and that's where JavaScript comes in.

You can check out this JSFiddle where an accordion has been created only with CSS:

http://jsbin.com/UnEwelO/1/edit

You might also find this article interesting:

http://andydavies.me/blog/2012/08/13/what-if-we-could-use-css-to-manipulate-html-attributes/